# filter files by creation date using c#

Tags: c#

with the following code , I can merge text files which exist in a directory

```
 var allLines = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt")
                        .SelectMany(f => File.ReadLines(f));
File.WriteAllLines(outputFileName, allLines);
```

How can I modify it to merge files which date creation is today ?

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("");
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
```

How can I combine the piece of code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

var allLines = info.GetFiles("*.txt")
                   .Where(p => p.CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today)
                   .OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime)
                   .SelectMany(p => File.ReadAllLines(p.FullName));

File.WriteAllLines(outputFileName, allLines);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use File.GetCreationTime method:

```
var allLines = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                        .Where(path => File.GetCreationTime(path).Date == DateTime.Today)
                        .SelectMany(f => File.ReadLines(f));
```

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` would be better to use than `GetFiles`

Comment: Yeah, right, it starts enumerating faster, doesn't wait for all files to be retrieved, since it's IEnumerable. Missed that one, just followed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var allLines = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt")
    .Where(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
    .SelectMany(f => File.ReadLines(f));
```

Comment: DateTime.Now means exactly now, not "today"

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, you are right, but it was `p.CreationTime == DateTime.Now` before

Comment: @Andrew I should say both of your code won't compile since `Directory.GetFiles` returns `string[]` not `Fileinfo[]`. and also no reason to use `DateTime.Now.Date` that's why we have `DateTime.Today` property.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, thanks for DateTime.Today, somehow I didn't know about it for 7 years:)